# EF code first 4.1 one to many bi-directional setup

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Items).WithRequired();
```

The model looks like

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item    
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

When EF generates the database for me I end up with two foreign keys in the Items table (User_Id and User_Id1) instead of just one. How would I configure this so only one key is created for me?

Just for testing purposes I removed the User from the Item class and in that case the configuration works just fine and only one key is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is just a typo in your question, but I'm pretty sure your modelBuilder statement should be `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Items).WithRequired(i => i.User);`

Not sure if that's your issue or not, but I'd certainly start there.

You probably also want to add the Long ID FK in your Item class

```
public class Item
{
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public long UserId {get; set;} //links directly to UserId

   public string Title {get; set;}

   public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: It was not a typo and it was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas - then you could up vote the answer and/or accept it.